# Not able find verifymail

Tags: javascript, html

My code is not able to find verifymail. What is exactly going wrong and what steps on how to solve it. Any help like point out what is wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="../JS/forgetpasswordemail.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-text">StudentLink</div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-picture"></div>
        <div class="eye-segment">
            <div class="eye-segment-black1"></div>
            <div class="eye-segment-black2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="create-account">Forget Password</div>
        <div class="background-section">Please Type the email address associated with the account</div>
        <form id="myForm"> 
            <button type="" style=" padding: 10px;
            left: 666px;
            top: 626px;
            position: absolute;
            background: white;
            border-radius: 5px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 10px;
            display: inline-flex;" onClick="verifymail()">Enter</button>
            <div class="password-container" style="top: 525px;">
                <input type="email" style="width: 1158px;
                padding: 10px;
                left: 141px;
                height:25px;
                border-color: black;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background:white ;" id="email-container input" placeholder="Email address"> 
            </div>
        </form>
        <!-- <div class="email-address-container">
            <input type="text" style="width: 1158px;
            padding: 10px;
            left: 141px;
            top: 431px;
            border-color: black;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background:white ;" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required> 
        </div> -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The verifymail() is present in the forgetpasswordemail.js

Comment: Where's your code for `onClick="verifymail()"`?

Comment: Since you have not provided a [mre], it's going to be very difficult for anyone to determine what the issue is without making assumptions that could easily be incorrect.  Please modify your question and supply one.

Comment: Once you code `forgetpasswordemail.js`. Once you say `forgetpassword.js`. 

Comment: My bad ```    function verifymail(){
        const email = emailInput.value;
        let data = {"email":email}
        $.ajax({
            url: 'forgetpasswordemail.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(response) {
            var message = response.message;
            console.log(message); // Outputs: Hello, John Doe!
            }
      });
    }```

Comment: Also the name is forgetpasswordemail.js my bad